# Can't access subfolder using a different DNS for the Texttalk platform

Tags: web, dns, subdirectory

As the title says I can't access a subfolder on my website while using a different DNS for the Texttalk platform.

The subfolder is "new" (ex. www.example.com/new) and I can't access it without getting the 404-screen.
How do I make the subfolder accessible while still keeping the DNS on the domain?

Thanks!